# Angular 5 SVG flowchart npm plugin

Tags: angular, flowchart

Hi I'm using Angular 5 in my project and I need to create flowcharts. I've searched and found some plugins but they don't offer these features that I need:

1. the Ability to add/delete/redraw the nodes (There should be an array of nodes so that when I update it, the flowchart is redrawn).
2. put a label on nodes and add tooltips to them.
3. being able to do some thing on clicking the nodes.
4. panning and zooming

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest `ngx-graph` which has all the features you've asked for. Take a look at the [demo](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/).
Here is the [link in github](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. But how can I update the flowchart? I push new items to nodes array but nothing changes.

Comment: @Kohtla You need to reassign the array (not sure if reassign is the correct word). push new nodes like this: `this.nodes = [...this.nodes, theNewNode]`.

Comment: how to change node style like diamond, also node background icon like that..?

Comment: @Manihtraa AFAIK you should do that yourself with svg in the template of your graph.

Comment: Is it possible to add a palette like node-red Editor in order to add new components /nodes ? : https://merakidemo.internetoflego.com/

Comment: Is there any mock data for this graph?

Answer (score 1):

In a commercial scenario, you might want to look at [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml). It can easily do all what you ask for in your list and has great [Angular integration](https://www.yworks.com/pages/angular-diagram-component) allowing you to both interactively and programmatically modify your diagrams, bind your data for both populating your graph structure and rendering your node visualizations,  tooltips, context menus, etc.

The library offers the widest available range of [automatic layout algorithms](https://www.yworks.com/pages/automatic-graph-drawing) so that you don't need to arrange your diagram yourself, but can get nice drawings from bound data, easily.

Although it is a pure JavaScript library, it provides complete TS bindings for the whole library, so you can choose between JS and TS or have both during development and get decent code completion and documentation lookup.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates that library, however I don't represent my employer on SO.</sup>

Comment: $15,000+... ya... nope.

Comment: That's the case I'll rather choose to develop it myself. This would be a great library, but for my need is too much especially for 15K. :D